# time sync server client java application

Tags: java, time, synchronization

I am looking for a sample java code which reads time from a particular server (could be a webservice or could be some bytes using TCP) and sets its on client machine. This could be achieved easily if you dont consider latency and compromise on those millisecond/nanosecond differences. I would like to have a pseudo-code for server and client, or an algorithm to achieve this.

Also I would like to know how NTP servers set time on client servers? Is there any white paper that explains this?

Answer (score 0):

Answers are here. For more results you may google with keywords like "NTP architecture" or similar
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol
http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/TimePrecision-HOWTO/ntp.html